# Continuously Loading Markers from database depending on last loaded timestamp

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, timestamp, setinterval

I have marker locations saved in a database with lat, lng, type, and timestamp. My current code loads all markers (displaying different Icons depending on their type), but when I use the setInterval function they all reload again. One solution that was suggested to me was to add a variable that checks the timestamp on the first successful load and updates it each time, so when the function is triggered again it will only load markers added after that time. However I'm not sure how I would go about adding this in to my current code. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
setInterval(function(){   

//Load Markers from the XML File
$.get("json-data-locations_2.php", function(data) {
    $(data).find("marker").each(function() {
        var type = $(this).attr('type');
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('lat')), parseFloat($(this).attr('lng')));

        var icons; 

        if (type === 'Drink') {
            icons = 'NewMarkers/Blue.png';
        }
        else if (type === 'Food') {
            icons = 'NewMarkers/Orange.png';
        }
        else {
            icons = 'NewMarkers/Purple.png';
        }

        create_marker(point, type, "", false, false, false, icons);

    });
});
}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

An other approach could be this one.
Call the function you allready have just once, then use setInterval on a new same function and only change the .php file you request data from to a new one that returns the latest marker based on the timestamp with a query like:

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it working using your approach but used this query instead: SELECT * FROM HotspotTable WHERE timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 15 SECOND) AND NOW() ORDER BY timestamp. And I call the setInterval every 15 seconds. Thanks